# Grails throws a 404 error when canceling a page request with a filter

Tags: grails, grails-filters

I have a filter:

```
class MyFilters {
    def filters = {
        before = {
            render(view: "/test")
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

This works great on pages where I'm using a controller to handle the request, showing the contents of test.gsp instead of the page I requested. However, when I try to access a page that maps directly to a GSP file, I get a 404 error.

Changing the render to simply `render "test"` produces the same results, as does commenting it out and just leaving the `return false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grails is a MVC framework. If you want to map an URL directly to a GSP (without redirection through a controller and action) you need to explain this to grails within your `UrlMappings.groovy`. There you can define your "shortcuts". E.g.:

```
static mappings = {
    "/$viewName"(view:"/index") {
        constraints {
            viewName([some constraints])
        }
    }
}
```

Which will render `views/index.gsp` without going through a controller.  If you do NOT define a controller mapping (or at least a view mapping) for those URLs, you canNOT use grails filters:

If you really want to intercept ALL requests, you can add a servlet filter to your grails application like this:

```
import javax.servlet.*

import org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils;

class TestFilter implements Filter {

    def applicationContext

    void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
        applicationContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(config.servletContext)
    }

    void destroy() {
    }

    void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        System.out.println("this filter has been called");
    }
}
```

In here you can do your redirections or renderings based on the `applicationcontext` and the current `request`.

You need to add this filter to your `web.xml`. On how to do this, have a look at: [How do i use a servlet in my grails app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9924616/how-do-i-use-a-servlet-in-my-grails-app/9928748#9928748)

Comment: I should have clarified. I am not normally redirecting to `/test.gsp`, only in certain cases, which is why it's necessary to do it with a filter instead of a URL mapping (unless there's a way to make conditional mappings?)

Comment: What kind of constraints you have? Is it something related to DB or some static constraints?

Comment: The things I'm checking aren't related to the problem. The problem exists without doing any checks.

Comment: A filter will not be called if there is no controller. What you are trying to accomplish is not possible without a urlmapping to a "dummy" controller or writing a container filter manually.

Comment: I guess because the answer was only edited and not new, I will not receive the bounty? However, if there anything unclear, tell me :-)

Comment: I forgot to hit "+200" and just accepted. Should be good now.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your app is doing the right thing. It is showing a 404 because */views/test.gsp* does not exist. When I change the code to the following, it works for me.

```
class MyFilters {
    def filters = {
        StackOverflowTestFilter (controller:'*') {
            before = {
                render("Hello World!")
                // also fine: render(controller:"mycontroller", action:"myaction")
                return false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, are you aware, that having return false will always cancel the rest of the flow? Return **false** only if the filter notices some violation of whatever you want to filter.

Hope this helps!

Comment: `/views/test.gsp` does exist. It displays fine when I use the same filter on a page which is generated via a controller, but on a page generated via a GSP, I get the strange 404 error.

Comment: Also note that just doing `render "test"` in the filter also produces a 404 error. It seems to be related to the `return false`.

Comment: Did you try the code I posted? It is returning *false* and rending *Hello World* - so that is definitely not it. I also noted that you did not define a filter name and scope in your example (in mine that would be `stackOverflowTestFilter (controller:'*')`). Looking at [the Grails documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#applyingFilters) it seems you have to provide that.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the http status code easily with the status argument of the Grails render method

I have not tested this with filters but with beforeIntecerptors in Grails controllers it works.

```
class MyFilters {
    def filters = {
        before = {
            render(view: "/test", status:200)
            return false
        }
    }
}
```