# Setting up the filter without controllers

Tags: grails, servlet-filters, url-mapping

I have a running tomcat at `localost`.

I wish to write a grails filter such that when ever user goes to `localhost/filter/` intercept the call and do some processing. I created a filter which is inside `conf` folder

```
class TestFilters {

    def filters = {
        filter(uri:'/filter') {
            before = {
            }
            after = {                    
            }
            afterView = {                   
            }
        }
    }        
}
```

after setting this up when I go to `localhost/filter/` I get only `404` error.

Where I'm making the mistake?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have no `FilterController` the url `localhost/filter` has no ressource to show - so you get a 404 error. You have to adapt your `UrlMappings` so that `localhost/filter` is a valid url of application.

Add the following to `UrlMappings.groovy`:

```
"/filter" (controller: "yourController", action:"yourAction")
```

Now - the url `localhost/filter` points to `yourAction` in `yourController` and the filter should be applied.

Comment: There is no other way in which I can do this without creating the controller? Are there any way to do so by changing `web.xml` file?

Comment: If you really want to ignore the whole MVC pattern you could link the url mapping directly to a view. Have a look at [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9890039/1230366) I found ...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But are there any way to put the filter routing in `UrlMapping`?